# In Vue - what's the difference between this.$data.foo vs this.foo?

Tags: vue.js

I'm curious since both seem to work and I'm having trouble finding an answer in the Vue docs. Is there a reason you should refer to data in Vue as `this.$data.whatever` vs just `this.whatever`?

Comment: where did you see $data in the docs?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data, and both were being used interchangeably within a Vue instance in a project I was looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data with $ prefix is specifically defined for accessing vue data property rather than user defined property.

For eg.

```
var data = { foo: 'foo' } // user defined data
var inst = new Vue({ data: { foo: 'foo' } }) // data - built-in vue property

data.foo // user defined data
inst.$data.foo // vue property - data
```

When you're inside the Vue hooks, you can just simply use `this.foo` for eg. inside computed method.

For more detail, you can see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)

Answer (score 1):

The $data attribute is used to access the data property outside the component:

```
var data = { a: 1 }

// direct instance creation
var vm = new Vue({
  data: data
})
vm.a // => 1
vm.$data === data // => true

// must use function when in Vue.extend()
var Component = Vue.extend({
  data: function () {
    return { a: 1 }
  }
})
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data